# Error initializing block database. Do you want to rebuild the block database now?

Tags: bitcoind, database, bitcoin.conf, regtest

I'm trying to set up a test network consisting of 3 nodes, each with different bitcoin.conf. I've constructed the directory and the .conf-files similar to what is the state of the art in qa/pull-tester/.
Within the terminal inside the node-A-directory I commanded: ...

```
bitcoind -conf="/home/me/.bitcoin/regtest/testnetwork/A/bitcoin.conf"
```

...and got back this error:

**'*Error initializing block database. Do you want to rebuild the block database now?*'**

My bitcoin.conf has following content:

```
regtest=1
rpcuser=rt //adopted from .conf-files in qa/pull-tester/
rpcpassword=rt //adopted from .conf-files in qa/pull-tester/
port=11111 //arbitrary free port
rpcport=21111 //arbitrary free port
```

Could someone please help with my intended network setup or at least say what I'm doing wrong?

PS: I'm going to paste my logfile in a comment below.

Comment: logfile: http://pastebin.com/aq4XpBNG

Comment: Are you using different datadir's? Does the problem only occur when you run multiple instances?

Comment: Actually the error is given at trying to start the first node - in my case node A.  I solved the problem by adding -regtest, -daemon and -datadir="path to node directory" to my previous command ... but after trying to getbalance another error appeared saying "couldn't connect to server."

Comment: Are you providing the same -conf option to `bitcoin-cli`?

Comment: No I just do: 'bitcoin-cli regtest getbalance' ... Do I need to give -conf as parameter for every and each API command? Or did I just misunderstand your question?

Comment: Any ideas someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the question is already answered in the comments and there anothere question arouse about how to send API commands independently to the server from each node.

As Nick ODell gave a correct hint, in fact you need to prefix each API command like "getbalance" with "bitcoin-cli -conf="!

Thanks to Nick ODell!